# PHP header not working ($_SESSION)

Tags: php, session, http-headers

I use this piece of code for my login form.

```
<?php

  include('session.php');

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/account.php/');
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AMP : Log In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
       echo $_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Yet when I try to redirect it does not work. On my session.php file I have:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = 'John';
```

Still it will echo out the name 'John', while it won't redirect to the account.php page, in the header() function.

I've used this before, but I see do something wrong. While I have the PHP code above the HTML.

Could someone explain to me why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header('http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/account.php/');` does not mean a thing to the browser and gets ignored.

You probably want to add "Location:" to it to redirect somewhere:

```
 header('Location: http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/account.php/');
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't fix your problem try adding: ob_start(); to the top of the file.

Comment: There is no evidence of "headers already sent" errors in the question, so there is no need to fix that. Also, adding `ob_start()` might not fix it if the space or BOM is at the start of the first script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the header you are sending and add an exit statement, so the redirect is getting through.

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location:http://www.askmephilosophy.co.nf/account.php/');
    exit();
  }
```

Comment: The exit is not mandatory. In fact it is suggested to add a page with a manual link that points to the same location where the automatic redirect is going, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: If you don't exit, the script continues running until it reaches the end which is not really necessary.

Comment: i dont know why they have down-voted,even if all what you said is correct